# APEX dynamically define default filename?

Tags: report, filenames, oracle-apex

In an APEX application, I have an interactive report.
In `Report Attributes > Report Export > Filename`, you can specify what file name you the download to have as a default.

Question:  Is there a way to dynamically define this default filename?

Yes, I know, the user can change it when they do the download.  But my boss wants the user to not to have to change the file name.

What can anyone tell me?  Thanks!!

APEX 4.2
Windows 7
IE 11

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this.  Create a hidden page item (e.g. `P1_REPORT_NAME`) and set its value to be whatever you want the name of the file to be.  You can calculate this in many different ways e.g. - pass a value through a link from another page, using a dynamic action or computation, or setting a default value via static content or pl/sql expression. Then navigate to `Report Attributes > Report Export > Filename` and set it to `&P1_REPORT_NAME.` - now the report will be called whatever the value of `P1_REPORT_NAME` is.

Comment: Also, you need to submit this item in the table region in the section "Page Items to Submit"