# Using substitution string for dynamic filename for download in interactive grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I want to set the filename for download of an interactve grid (Application Express 5.1.0.00.45) dynamically to a combination of a timestamp and the page alias.

What I've already done:

1. step: As mentioned in http://oraclequirks.blogspot.com/2008/02/build-and-use-apex-page-alias.html I've built a application item to get a substitution string for the page alias. => Works fine!
2. step: As mentioned in [APEX dynamically define default filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831468/apex-dynamically-define-default-filename/55950007#55950007) I've generated a page item (P510_FILENAME) which shows the filename I would like to use. => Works fine!
3. step: To use the content of this page item P510_FILENAME as filename I've set `Report Attributes > Report Export > Filename` to `&P510_FILENAME.`. => But when I try to download the interactive grid, it shows `&p510_filename..csv_` as filename!

So I have to problems:

1. The substitution string doesn't get replaced by the content of the page item P510_FILENAME. Also if I directly use my application item `&APP_PAGE_ALIAS.`it doesn't get replaced. But the (at the moment not hidden) page item P510_FILENAME shows the correct filename.
2. The file extension is set to '.csv_' instead of '.csv'. All the same when I try to download a HTML file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Late answer for anyone seeing it in the future:

when using substitution string for downloading a file of a table, you need to submit that item in the table region:

[image]

and then you can this item in the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

For &. type substitution string should be all caps.

In this name &p510_filename..csv_ it looks like it was entered in lower case. Please try with the exact(case sensitive) name.

Ex: [image: substitution string for filename]